# MongoDB query on objects in an array based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a players inventory that looks like this.

```
let inventory = [ { name: 'Wood', amount: 6 }, { name: 'Stone', amount: 2 } ]
```

This is the players resources.

I also have a list of craftable items.

```
{"name":"CraftingTable","craftingReagents":[{"name":"Stone","amount":"2"}]}
{"name":"CraftingTable2","craftingReagents":[{"name":"Wood","amount":"4"}]}
{"name":"CraftingTable3","craftingReagents":[{"name":"Wood","amount":"5"},{"name":"Stone","amount":"2"}]}
```

The items schema is as such

```
let itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name:String,
        craftingReagents: [
            {
                name: String,
                amount: Number
            }
        ]

    }
);
```

I want a query that will return all craftable objects where the players inventory has sufficient resources to do so.

For example with 6 Wood and 2 Stone the query should return all 3 crafting tables, as the player has sufficient resources to craft all three

This is what I have so far, and I am very lost. Please help!

```
itemModel.find({
     craftingReagents: {
          $all: [{
               $elemMatch: {
                    name: {
                         $in: [
                              'Wood'
                         ]
                    },
                    amount: { $lte: 6 }
                    }
               },
               {
               $elemMatch: {
                    name: {
                         $in: [
                              'Stone'
                              ]
                         },
                    amount: { $lte: 2 }
               }
          }
     ]
}
});
```

Heres the thing. The players inventory can change to an infinite number of different resources. AND the craftable objects can have an infinite number of different requirments. I meerly gave an example of what the inventory, and craftable objects could look like.

How do you list documents that the player has enough resources to craft?

Comment: Below query would get you what you've asked for but I've a question is that ok for you to return `CraftingTable3` even though it has only `{"name":"Wood","amount":"5"}` but you're inventory has `{"name":"Wood","amount":"6"}` ?? anyway it does satisfy `{ name: 'Stone', amount: 2 }` is one match ok ??

Comment: CraftingTable3 has 5 *Required* Wood. So if the player has enough wood, it would return CraftingTable3, as long as the player also had enough Stone. In this example if the player had 5 or more wood, AND 2 or more stone. it would return craftingTable3

Comment: So with this request `let inventory = [ { name: 'Wood', amount: 1 }, { name: 'Stone', amount: 2 } ]` ----> what all has to be returned from collection ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
itemModel.find({
    $or: [{ craftingReagents: { $elemMatch: { name: 'Wood', amount: { $lte: 6 } } } },
    { craftingReagents: { $elemMatch: { name: 'Stone', amount: { $lte: 2 } } } }]
})
```

Comment: Heres the thing. The players inventory can change to an infinite number of different resources. AND the craftable objects can have an infinite number of different requirments. I meerly gave an example of what the inventory, and craftable objects could look like.

Comment: @noahn567 : Even though that's the case all you need to do is, 1) Query does look the same if it works for you with this sample data !! 2) when you're about to send this query to DB from code you need to list all the objects in this structure of the query !!